# Ограничить кол-во выводимых символов из базы данных mysql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

подскажите как правильно ограничить кол-во выводимых символов из базы данных phpmyadmin, при этом оставив ограничение по выводу записей.

```
        <?php
                $new = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM `news` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2");
                $new = mysqli_fetch_all($new);
                foreach ($new as $new){
            ?>
              <p class="heder"><?= $new[2] ?></p>
              <p class="date"><?= $new[3] ?></p>

            <?php
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/mb_substr

Comment: Как вариант можно применить пользовательскую функцию к sql запросу, для обрезки данных из определённых столбцов, но это не снизит трафик... Проще обрезать переменную.

Comment: Спасибо за подсказки, буду разберется)

Answer (score 0):

Пошел более простым путём. Не ограничил БД в выводе символов, но при это ограничил "p" на символы следующим образом:

```css
  display: block;
  width: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
```

Comment: Вот пользователи удивлятся почему страница с двумя абзацами грузится по десять минут.